# Can not add property to an interface for passport-linkedin-oauth2 declaration file

Tags: typescript, type-declaration, .d.ts

I'm trying add a property to 'StrategyOption' interface for 'passport-linkedin-oauth2' declaration file. It does not declare any module or interface. Just export interfaces and class

```
....
export interface StrategyOption {
    clientID: string;
    clientSecret: string;
    callbackURL: string;

    scopeSeparator?: string;
    enableProof?: boolean;
    profileFields?: string[];
}
....
export class Strategy extends passportStrategy {...}
```

I've tried with those following method. But all those are failed

```
/// <reference types="passport-linkedin-oauth2" />
export {}

declare global {
  export interface StrategyOption {
    scope?: string[] // does not work
  }
}
```

and

```
export interface StrategyOption {
  scope?: string[] // does not work
}
```

and

```
interface StrategyOption {
  scope?: string[] // does not work
}
```

Is there any way to add property this type of declaration file?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found the idea. It's all about [augmetation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

So my code should be

```
import 'passport-linkedin-oauth2'

declare module 'passport-linkedin-oauth2' {
  interface StrategyOption {
    scope?: string[]
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure about how much importance has the following configuration

In `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
....
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["/src/types/*", "node_modules/*"]
    }
}
```

Need extension declaration file to be in the `/src/types/` directory in my case without any sub-directory.